# pip install python-dateutil does not work

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, python-dateutil

The command:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Give this error:

```
Collecting python-dateutil
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-dateutil (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-dateutil
```

But easy_install python-dateutil  works fine....

Comment: What version of Python are you using? With python 2.7 and pip 8.1.2, `pip install python-dateutil` works just fine.

Comment: Anaconda,  python 3.5,  pip 8.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in  ~/.pip/pip.conf

it should have been like:

```
[global]
index-url = https://pypi.python.org/simple
```

but I has it pointing to a different index